# Maximum revision count in svn (subversion)

Tags: svn, revision

I'm working with subversion, but I have to commit lots and lots of revisions so I just wanted to know, is there a maximum number for revision count? And if there is what is it? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum revision number supported by SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816523/what-is-the-maximum-revision-number-supported-by-svn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What is the maximum revision number supported by SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816523/what-is-the-maximum-revision-number-supported-by-svn)

If you're using a 32-bit computer it's 2147483647, that's 231-1, the maximum value of a signed 32-bit integer.